# Python string function isidentifier()

Tags: python, string

I'm working through a Python 3 book and came across the string function isidentifier().  The text description is "s.isidentifier() : Returns True if s is non empty and is a valid identifier".  I tested it in the Python Shell like this:

```
>>> s = 'test'
>>> s.isidentifier()
True
>>> 'blah'.isidentifier()
True
```

I would expect the 2nd statement to return false since 'blah' is not held in a variable.  Can anyone explain this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Returns True if s is non empty and is a **valid** identifier.

What they mean is that s *could* be valid as an identifier. It doesn't imply that it is an identifier that's in use.

Your first example is showing the same thing: 'test' (what `isidentifier` is actually checking) is not the name of a variable either. I think you meant

```
>>> 's'.isidentifier()
True
```

Comment: To write what rosscj2533 *thought* it was, I guess you could do isidentifier() first and then do an eval() and see if it gives you a NameError or not.

Comment: Ah, I was taking it as is currently a valid identifier that's in use. Thanks.

Comment: @MatrixFrog - much better to test for existence of this identifier in locals() and globals(), rather than eval()'ing it.  Faster *and* safer.

Answer (score 5):

"isidentifier" doesn't say anything about the "variable" the string being tested is referenced by.  So

```
'blah'.isidentifier()
```

is identical to

```
s = 'blah'
s.isidentifier()
```

In Python, it's never (or rarely) about the "variable" (Python doesn't have variables), it's about the *object*.  In this case, strings.

Answer (score 5):

Python doesn't have "variables".  It is more helpful to think in terms of *objects*.

`'blah'` definitely exists at the time `'blah'.isidentifier()` is called (after all it means that "call `isidentifier()` method of the string object `'blah'`").

So if your understanding were correct, `isidentifier()` method of string objects should always return `True`, because at the time of the call, the object definitely exists.

What `isidentifier()` does is to check that the string object can be used as a valid identifier.  Try these two lines in your Python session for example:

```
>>> a = "$"
>>> "$".isidentifier()
```

Even though `"$"` is assigned to the name `a`, the `isidentifier()` call returns `False` since `$` is not a valid identifier in Python.

Answer (score 4):

`isidentifier` is a Python function that simply tests whether a string contains only certain characters (underscore, digits, and alphas) and starts with an alpha or an underscore, so the string can be used for a valid Python identifier. Other functions that test for character classes are `isalpha`, `isalnum`, `isdigit`, and others.

```
ss = (
    'varABC123',
    '123ABCvar',
    '_123ABCvar',
    'var_ABC_123',
    'var-ABC-123',
    'var.ABC.123',
    # check your own strings
)

fmt = '%-15s%-10s%-10s%-10s%-10s' 
print(fmt % ('', 'isalpha', 'isalnum', 'isdigit', 'isidentifier'))
for s in ss:
    print(fmt % (s, s.isalpha(), s.isalnum(), s.isdigit(), s.isidentifier()))
```

Result:

```
               isalpha   isalnum   isdigit   isidentifier
varABC123      False     True      False     True      
123ABCvar      False     True      False     False     
_123ABCvar     False     False     False     True      
var_ABC_123    False     False     False     True      
var-ABC-123    False     False     False     False     
var.ABC.123    False     False     False     False
```